# getting "img" id with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have this code:

```html
<div id="popupContactIMG_4179" class="xxxx">
    <a id="popupContactCloseIMG_4179">x</a>
    <img alt="" src="../IMG_4179.jpg" id="id1">
</div>
```

I want to get the `img` id which is inside the `<a>` on mouse click on `<a>`:

```
$("a[id^=popupContactClose]").click(function(){ 
    var qwerty = $(this+" img").attr("id");
}
```

Any help?

Comment: <div id="popupContactIMG_4179" class="xxxx"> 
    <a id="popupContactCloseIMG_4179">x</a> 
    <img alt="" src="../IMG_4179.jpg" id="id1"> 
    </div>

Comment: i forgot this :  <img alt="" src="../IMG_4179.jpg" id="id1">

Comment: Your `<img>` tag _has no ID_ ....

Comment: Your `img` element doesn't have an ID. What value are you expecting to return?

Comment: @rolandfeghaly That makes more sense! I've edited the question

Comment: The `img` is not inside the `a` element in your code.

Comment: You really should use a class rather than selecting elements by like `$("a[id^=popupContactClose]")`.

Comment: mmm , thats a good idea , think so , but i need to get the code works for now , after i will see what changes i can do , thank u

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) (as the `img` is the following sibling):

```
$("a[id^=popupContactClose]").click(function(){ 
    var qwerty = $(this).next().attr("id");
});
```

Alternatively, which is what you appear to been attempting to do, is pass the parent of `this` as the context to jQuery:

```
$("a[id^=popupContactClose]").click(function(){ 
    var qwerty = $("img", $(this).parent()).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) Just be aware that `next` will stop working if you change the HTML structure to add a new element between the `img` and the `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$("a[id^=popupContactClose]").click(function(){ 
 var qwerty = $(this).siblings("img").first().attr("id");
}
```

Comment: `.find()` won't work here because the `img` is not a child of the `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<img>` tag has no ID, but if it did, you could use this:

```
$("a[id^=popupContactClose]").click(function(){ 
   var qwerty = this.nextSibling.id;
});
```

although that'll only work if you know for certain that the `<img>` tag is the very next element after the `<a>` tag.

If you can't guarantee that, then use jQuery:

```
$("a[id^=popupContactClose]").click(function(){ 
   var qwerty = $(this).next('img').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: @JamesAllardice so it is - didn't notice - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("a[id^=popupContactClose]").click(function(){ 
    var qwerty = $("img", $(this).parent()).attr("id");
}
```

Your question seems to imply that the `img` should be inside the `a` element - yet it isn't, is that a typo?

Also, the `img` has no `id` attribute - is that another typo?